# Populating a div with php file that processes a form

Tags: php, html, uploading

I have a link on a website when it's clicked it will load a form in a div. The form is processed by a PHP script. I need the output from the PHP script to appear in that  div. Any idea how to do this? Thanks

File header.php

```
<html>
    <head>


    <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#mylink').click(function(){

                       $('#content').load("form.php");
                  });    

          });

</script>

</head>

<body>


     <li><a href="#" id="mylink">Add Account</a></li>
```

file index.php

```
<?php

       include_once 'header.php';

 ?>


 <div id="content"></div>
```

in form.php

```
  <form id= method="POST" action="script.php">
        ......
        ........

     <input type="submit" value="Add account" />

 </form>
```

in script.php

i need to send error message or thank you note in div #content

Comment: *" Any idea how to do this?"* - Plenty of ideas. Have any code to boot?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax may help you. It's easy to do so. Try it.

Comment: can you call ajax from php?

Answer (score 0):

First, this sounds like a job that JavaScript would be perfect for. But if you want to go old school, once you submit your form, depending if you set it to be method="post" or method="get" in the form tag, you can access it with php in the receiving script with $_GET or $_POST.

example:

html:
`<form action="yourScript.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="location" />`

php (file: yourScript.php): `echo $_POST['location'];`